# Is it possible to use Compiz with GNOME Flashback on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, compiz, gnome-flashback

As in title - is it possible to use Compiz with GNOME Flashback on Ubuntu 20.04 ? If yes, how ?
It would be nice to have some features like window overview screen with miniatures of all open windows, something that Compiz provided in the older version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The corresponding `compiz-gnome` package is [in place](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=compiz-gnome).

So it should work after you install it with

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-gnome
```

and optionally set settings using CompizConfig Settings Manager (`ccsm`):

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then select relevant session on login screen.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Gnome Session Flashback can be used both with metacity and with compiz. In addition to installing `gnome-session-flashback`, you need to install compiz::

```
sudo apt-get -y install compiz-plugins compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Select the "GNOME Flashback (Compiz)" session during login.

Comment: Compiz was not installed by default with system installation. I needed also to install compiz itself, not only compiz-plugins and compizconfig-settings-manager. After installing all these and restarting the computer, I was able to choose GNOME Flashback Compiz session.

Comment: Installing compiz-plugins will automatically pull in compiz as well.

Comment: After those package installs, I could get compiz settings to run alright, but couldn't get any of its effects (e.g. the window switching cube) actually happen after being selected. Maybe I really need the flashback version of gnome, but wasn't brave enough to make the switch from the version of gnome shipped with 20.04. Didn't get a new session login option either. [Some extra steps listed here](https://linuxconfig.org/enabling-ubuntu-compiz-3d-cube-desktop-effect) feel outdated.